# naming of ViewModel

Tags: c#, oop, naming-conventions

I am writing a Web app from scratch and i am a little confused in naming of view models

In this app  have a `BaseViewModel` which is almost blank as their might be some pages in the app that don't need header and footer such as invoice etc so i have decided to make a new ViewModel named `XViewModel` which inherits from `BaseViewModel` and it will contain the object of `HeaderViewModel` and `FotterViewModel`. hence `TrainerBaseViewModel` and `UserBaseViewModel` is derived from that `XViewModel`.

The problem is now sorted by creating `XViewModel` but what should be the name of `XViewModel` as per Best Practices

Comment: This is highly subjective, i doubt there is a "best practice" for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call it a "DocumentViewModel" as it is a type of page that contains Header and Footer.

Comment: If you are using it in your code then please consider accepting the answer too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to pick a naming convention that is understandable directly from the context (without a need for a "key" or "dictionary") and stick with it.

Comment: Thanks @baruch but can you suggest me some name for this

Comment: @rajansoft1 `FullViewModel`? `ExtendedViewModel`? `MainViewModel`?

Comment: Hey Thanks again, these names looks nice but doesn't go with my app